# nodejs timer not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, timer, socket.io

```
count=0;

  setInterval(function(){
    sequelize
      .authenticate()
      .then(function() {
        count = count +1;
        console.log(count.toString());
        socket.emit("cloud_database_status", "online");
      }, function () {
        socket.emit("cloud_database_status", "offline");
    });
  },2000);
```

I have this set of code in my node.js file. When I run the console timer it doesn't works correctly sometimes. When I ran the code first it did increment the count 1 every 2 seconds. and when I stopped and ran again it started to increment in random times some times in 1 second some time in 2 seconds some times in three seconds and so on. like so 1 --- 1 sec delay, 2----1 second delay, 3----2 second delay, 4---3 seconds delay. whats wrong with my code?

Answer (score 0):

Because of it's async, You've to have control on process when it will finish and etc.

Sequelize automatically connects to db when You do:

```
var sequelize = new Sequelize('connection string');
```

`authenticate` does simply `SELECT 1+1 AS result` to check if it's ok with connection that returns in promise.

so the promise will have `err` as result - that will indicate that something is wrong with connection.

Problem of `de-synchronization` could be network, database performance/business and many other factors. To avoid that You need to take control of scheduling.

So simply do this:

```
var async = require('async'); // npm i --save async

// creating custom object in sequelize object to track connection
sequelize.databaseConnectionStatus = {
  connected: true, 
  status: 'online', 
  lastError: ''
}; 
async
  .forever(function(next) {
    sequelize
      .authenticate()
      .then(function(err) {
        sequelize.databaseConnectionStatus.connected = (err) ? false : true;
        sequelize.databaseConnectionStatus.status = (err) ? 'offline' : 'online';
        sequelize.databaseConnectionStatus.lastError = err;
        if(err) console.error(err);

        setTimeout(next, 5000); // running check every 5 seconds
      });
  });

var count=0;
setInterval(function() { // independent loop to read connection status and emit by socket
    count++;
    socket.emit("cloud_database_status", sequelize.databaseConnectionStatus.status);
}, 2000);
```